# How to iterate through Mongo Collection and perform db operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

currently I have a Mongo Shell script, it will delete any duplicates if there's 500 or more.

```
db.Documents.aggregate([
{
 $group: {
    _id: { projectId: "$Filename" },
    dups: { $addToSet: "$_id"  },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
 }
},
 {
   $match:
     {
       count: {"$gt": 500}
     }
 }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
   doc.dups.shift();
   db.Documents.remove({
       _id: {$in: doc.dups}
   });
});
```

This code works perfectly when using mongo shell. I'm trying to convert this to execute via a script. Unfortunately I'm presented with

```
dbo.collection("Documents").aggregate([{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                projectId: "$Filename"
            },
            dups: {
                $addToSet: "$_id"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: {
                "$gt": 500
            }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.dups.shift();
    var myquery = {
        _id: {
            $in: doc.dups
        }            
    };

    dbo.collection("Documents", function(err, collection) {
       collection.deleteOne(myquery);
    });
   
});
```

Unfortunately I'm presented with `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited` when trying to execute

I understand this error, foreach isn't thread friendly and tried to convert to an array but was still presented with the error.

```
.toArray(function(err, result){
for (i = 0, count = result.length; i < count; i++) {
    var doc = result[i];
        doc.dups.shift();
        var myquery = {
            _id: {
                $in: doc.dups
            }            
        };

    dbo.collection("Documents", function(err, collection) {
             collection.deleteOne(myquery);
        });
}
});
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It is likely, the warning message is about the connection pool. You need to close the connection at the end of the program or task. Also, you can configure the pool size (and other attributes) as needed for your application. See [NodeJS Connection Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/connection/).

Comment: @prasad_ I am closing the connection in the end.

Comment: Then, try collect all the document id's in the array, and then delete them in a separate function using `deleteMany` method. This is efficient than sending one delete to the server at a time.